# Can this expression throw exception

Tags: c#, exception, wndproc, arithmeticexception

This is one of the lines I am having in C# app override of WndProc:

```
int hiWord = unchecked((short)((long)m.LParam >> 16)); 
if (hiWord != 0)
{
   // do something
}
```

Is it possible that it may throw Arithmetic exception?

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't throw exceptions, but you need to be fully aware of arithmetic details of right shift operator; that the highest order sign bit will be kept (if `LParam` is singed value), and the way `long` value will be truncated into `short`; that highest 48 order bits will be removed and the rest 16 bits will be returned only.

Comment: Can you explain why casting short to long will create overflow?

Comment: @LeonHavin There is no overflow in casting from long to short, it is a truncation. I edited my answer and removed the word overflow, as I just was trying to point at the right shift operator `>>`'s sign bit.